# CouchDB view URL shows: CouchDB: {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"} ... Why?

Tags: view, couchdb

For example:

- My CouchDB is hosted on: example.com
- The CouchDB database name is: foo
- The View name is: my_view

So, when I put these together to construct the URL, I get:

- http://www.example.com/foo/my_view

The above URL shows:

```
 {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

**Why is this error given?**

The expected result is that that the documents corresponding to the "my_view" view are listed.

More Info:

If I visit http://www.example.com/foo, I get the expected response:

```
{"db_name":"foo","...
```

If I visit http://www.example.com/foo/_design/my_view, I get the expected response:

```
{"_id":"_design/my_view","_rev":"...
```

I'm using CouchDB v1.0.2 on Windows7/Chrome

**Full content of my design document (real values shown, not example.com)**

```
{
  "_id":"_design/locations",
  "_rev":"1-0f7fbdd2f5b4213591e171b6e546af3a",
  "language":"javascript",
  "views": {
    "locations": {
      "map":"function(doc) {\n  emit(doc.type === \"location\" && doc.name);\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the full content of your design document?

Comment: You must not have your example URLs quite right...  Shouldn't the third on be http://www.example.com/foo/_design/my_design_doc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct URL path is `/<db>/_design/<design>/_view/<view>`.

From your real URL given in the comments, this would be the correct URL:

http://burritohunter.com/couchdb/burritohunter/_design/locations/_view/locations

And indeed it returns the expected view:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"86bb31389b78aa5921f7a2f5c0000915","key":"Billy's","value":null},
{"id":"jimmys","key":"Jimmy's","value":null}
]}
```

Querying only /_design/locations will return the document itself:

```
{"_id":"_design/locations","_rev":"1-0f7fbdd2f5b4213591e171b6e546af3a","language":"javascript","views":{"locations":{"map":"function(doc) {\n  emit(doc.type === \"location\" && doc.name);\n}"}}}
```

Comment: I get 404 when I try your path. But, this works: http://www.example.com/foo/_design/my_view (where "foo" is db name and "my view" is view name)

Comment: Really?  Given your design doc, the URL http://localhost:5984/<dbname>/_design/locations/_view/locations (adjusting the host:port part to fit your circumstances) should work.  That's exactly what the [Couch Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) tells you to use.

Comment: Updated Matt's answer with edt's real URLs